Changing port number of specific IP traffic
I have two computers, a master and a slave that need to talk to each other, but they are preprogrammed with different port number! Basically, the master send commands to port 2000, but the slave listen on port 4000.
How can I use a Raspberry Pi (RPI) to intercept the packets and convert the ports from 2000 to 4000, and 4000 to 2000 in the other direction?
All devices are on the same network, let say IP 10.1.1.10(master), 10.1.1.20(slave) and 10.1.1.30(RPI)
I can see examples where the packets goes through the RPI, between eth0 and wlan, but I want everything to go in and out of eth0.

Don't do it that way. Use mosquito and the MQTT protocol you will a) find it easier and b) have more success more quickly. You shouldn't be interested in port numbers that doesn't scale well. Use MQTT and the message originator/publisher chooses the topic that the message subscriber listens to. One or more publisher can communicate with one or more subscriber with no worries about port numbers.

please update your post ... describe what changes you are allowed to make to the two computers

The two computers are controllers, I have no visibility into them, I an not change them, they are from third parties.

If you could get the master to send the data to the Pi then you could use iptables and DNAT to reroute the traffic.  If you got 2 USB to RJ45 adapter plugged into the Pi and all the traffic had to go through the Pi then DNAT would work.
